# Parameterization of a curve (line & circle)

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

Let the curve C be the boundary of the region bounded by $y=2$ and $x^2+y^2=9$.

**a) How would C look like?**

(*I think it would be circle segment?*)

**b) Which of the following characteristics does C have?**

- smooth
- piece wise smooth
- Jordan curve
- closed

*(I think it is **closed** and **smooth** and also a **Jordan curve**?) But how can I prove this mathematically?*

**c) I need to find a parameterization of the curve**, and here I do not know how to start, do I parameterize the line and the circle arc separately?

the intersection points would be $P(\sqrt{5} | 2), Q(-\sqrt{5} | 2)$
[image]

Comment: For the parametrization you can start by seeing at what values of $x$ the circle crosses the line $y=2$ (plug in $y=2$ and solve for $x$) and then you can use $x=3cos\theta$ and $y=3sin\theta$ for the arc, finding the angle boundaries with the values of $x$ calculated and $y=2$. To parametrize a line $y=ax+b$, let $x=t$, then $y=at+b$

Comment: There are two such regions. That makes the problem ambiguous. However, the correct answers to b] do not depend on which region we use.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: I tried to calculate the angles, I set up the function $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and calculated $y'$ at the x-intersection points ($\sqrt{5}, -\sqrt{5}$). But what to do after that?

Comment: you can find the angle in the first quadrant by using the data you calculated, $\sqrt{5}$ is the base of the triangle of height 2, from then on it’s trig $tan\theta =\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$, the rules of $arctan$ apply, make sure when you take the inverse on both sides you don’t get the angle in the third quadrant because $\frac{-2}{-\sqrt{5}}$ also satisfies the criteria. To find the angle in the second quadrant, well, symmetry works in this case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the parametrization, if it is the upper sliver, you can solve the quadratic equation for $y$:

$y=\pm\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and since we’re working in $y>0$, simply $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}.$

Then letting $x=t$ we have the parametrization $(t,\sqrt{9-t^2})$ for $-\sqrt{5}\leq t\leq\sqrt{5}$.

Your line is $y=2$ thus the parametrization $(t,2)$ for $-\sqrt{5}\leq t\leq\sqrt{5}$.

These are easy ways to think of parameterizations at first, you can work your way to different methods such as polar coordinates.

Comment: thank you so much! so  $t$ is both times in $[-\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{5}]$?.

Comment: Yup! Plot a couple points for yourself to check :) that’s the whole point of a parametrization you can draw the curve based on t, sort of like tracking the movement of a fly (your point) in this case 2D space through time (t).

Comment: thank you so much! I have a follow up question, how could I calculate the tangent vector here? just differentiate each parameterization?

Comment: Sure, just watch out at the points of intersection $(\pm\sqrt{5},2)$

Comment: I do not know if I got it correctly, but I have  $(1, \frac{1}{2} \frac{-2t}{\sqrt{9-t^2}})$ and $(1,0)$ what exactly would happen at the intersection points?

Comment: From what you showed you have two tangent vectors at the same point, for further questions you can ask me [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics) :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving an explicit answer, I'll give you a plan on as how to think of this yourself.
The first thing I would recommend is drawing the two boundaries, you will earn lots of intuition about the problem.
Once you've done that, you will see the curve is a circle segment AND the segment joining the two ends since the radius is 3 > 2. Therefore it's not smooth, but piecewise-smooth since it fails on those two points (you will see it graphically), it is closed and a Jordan Curve.
As for the parametrization, draw the boundaries, and parametrize those two individually and then join them continuously. With that parametrization you can actually prove **(b)**

Comment: I have added the drawing, and the intersection points would be $P(\sqrt{5}|2)$, $Q(-\sqrt{5}|2)$, so for the circle part, i could choose the standard parameterization $x=3*cos t, y=3*sin t$ and for the straight line would the parameterization be $<t,2>$ ? Is this correct? if yes,  how to join them together? If not please give me further advice. thank you

Comment: ok, remember to define where t moves (get the angles of those points, $\theta_1$,$\theta_2$, anticlockwise). Then if you have $\phi$ and $\eta$, the two parametrizations, you can define $\psi (t)= \begin{cases}\phi(t) \quad\quad t\in[\theta_1,\theta_2] \\
\eta(t-\theta_2) \quad\quad t\in[\theta_2,p+\theta_2] \end{cases}$
the real parametrization of the entire curve

Comment: thanks for getting back to me,  I tried to calculate the angles, I set up the function $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and calculated $y'$ at the x-intersection points ($\sqrt{5}, -\sqrt{5}$). I got $\theta_1=-83.62°$, $\theta_2=83.62°$ But what to do after that? I am confused what exactly is $\eta$ and $\phi$ here? Because I still do not have the two parameterizations

Comment: $\phi(t) = (3cos(t),3sin(t))$ with $t\in[\theta_1,\theta_2]$ is the parametrization of the circle segment, $\eta(t) = (t,2)$ with $t\in[-\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5}]$ is the parametrization of the line. With what I told you in the previous comment you can get $\psi$ the parametrization of the boundary you needed, and with that draw conclusions about the curve. Its just concatenating the two appropiately